# Literal strings do not print as expected

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, locale

this sample cose does not print characters SBCS as instructions in MS guide

```
// utf8.cpp : Este archivo contiene la función "main". La ejecución del programa comienza y termina ahí.
//

#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>




   int main()
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, ".OCP");
        std::cout << "ácido acético en España es vinagre!\n";
            _getch();
            return 0;
    }
```

instead it prints

> ßcido acÚtico en Espa±a es vinagre!

Comment: What happens if you write the string as UTF8? Like this: `std::cout <<u8"ácido acético en España es vinagre!\n";`

Comment: Quimby has made mistake said u8 was not declared in this scope

Comment: What is that `".OCP"` locale?  Where did you get that string?  Anyway, the format you use in the string literals is controlled by the compiler (a compiling option), not by a library parameter to the `setlocale(3)` function.  Probably they differ.